# Print data from os.listdir() using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-lab

I'm having trouble pulling data from a folder that contains two csv files that is updated to replace the older of the two files every day. Because I always want to pull the last/-1/most recent file that is in that folder, what query can I run to pull the newest file using pandas in Python 3 on JupyterLab? When I print the data that I want to pull I receive None as a response.

**Python3 Code in JupyterLab:**

```
#install prep
%conda install pandas
import pandas as pd

#install 
import glob

#naming path for most recent file
FolderPath="Pathname of folder containing the two most recent csv files"

import os

#display name of most recent file in the pathname folder aka FolderPath
NewestData = os.listdir(FolderPath)
print(NewestData[-1])

#pull data from 'NewestData'
UpdatedData = pd.read(NewestData[-1])

print(UpdatedData)
```

Comment: Is the format of the data correct?  Also, it might be a folder, etc. You also need to add the folder directory in front of the `NewestData[-1]`  because it does not automatically add it.

Comment: As an aside, `os.listdir()` does not guarantee any particular order for the returned names. You should sort the result first.

Comment: Use glob to restrict to just the CSVs. `glob.glob(os.path.join(FolderPath, "*.csv"))`. Then, you still have to figure out which is newest. Is there a hint the file file name? You could use `os.stat(filename).st_mtime` for the last modified file. That doesn't always work - if the file was moved into the directory, its mtime doesn't change. On Windows use could use `st_ctime` but not on Linux where you actually need to change the file to get a changed timed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the file listed is indeed a file and not a folder, this should work.

```
FolderPath="C:/testpath"
NewestData = os.listdir(FolderPath)
UpdatedData = pd.read(os.path.join(FolderPath, NewestData[-1]))
```

The only difference is that you are not adding the `FolderPath` prefix to your listed directories, because OS does not do that automatically.

Comment: `os.path.join()` would be a better way to join path components. You don't need to take care of the trailing slash using it.

Comment: Thank you for this AKX, the solution you provided in this answer worked.